# My laptop's fan doesn't turn on every time I play, just once in a while

Tags: laptop, fan, lag

I have a question. Since a bought my laptop (DELL), sometimes the fan turns on and sometimes the fan doesn't turn on. I don't know why this happens. When I'm playing any game, if the fan is on, I have no problems, I don't have any lag. On the other hand, when I'm playing any game and the fan isn't making any noise, my laptop gets very hot and my game always gets lagged. Does someone know how to turn on the fan when I wish it turns on? My laptop's fan turns on when it wants. I hate it :(. I would like it turns on every time I'm playing! Can someone help me? Does someone know how to do/fix that? I think it isn't a hardware problem, just a software problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure because every laptop is different but have you tried changing power settings to 'Performance' mode?

Comment: Using the Dell Driver Update app, update BIOS and update the Power Driver. Then update anything else it suggests.  Then update Windows completely, restart and check the fan.

Comment: didn't work, @Itai :(

Comment: Sorry, without more details on the model number, we are only guessing.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 5558, @Itai